# isdigit() and isalpha() return type 0? or whats going on here.?

Tags: c, function, validation, return-value, header-files

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void printSquare( char c, int size);

int main(){

    int userNum;
    char userChar;

    printf("Enter a character : \n");
    scanf("%s",&userChar);

    while(isalpha(userChar) == 0){
        printf("Enter a character : \n");
        scanf("%s",&userChar);
    }

    printf("Enter a number(3-10) : \n");
    scanf("%d",&userNum);

    while(isdigit(userNum) == 0){
        printf("Enter a number(3-10) : \n");
        scanf("%d",&userNum);
    }   

    printSquare(userChar,userNum);

}
```

/*printSquare function gets a char and number from the user,
the number the user enters is how many letters AND rows get 
printed to output.

so if user enters 'a' and number '3' output is abc \n bcd \n cde 
im having trouble with the validation in the main. using the function isalpha()
to check if return value if 0, if yes then continue prompting user for char
i tried doing the same thing for isdigit() but it goes into an infite loop
has anyone seen this before, does it have anything to do with the buffer or stdin??*/

```
void printSquare( char c, int size){
    char letters[27] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
    int initChar;

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(letters)/sizeof(letters[i]); i++)
    {
        if (c == letters[i])
        {
            initChar = i;
            printf("FOUND IT - > %c\n",letters[i]);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = initChar; j <  initChar + size; j++)
        {
            printf("%c",letters[j % 27] );
        }
        printf("\n");
        initChar+=1;
    }
}
```

Comment: In `scanf("%s",&userChar);`, `%s` is for strings. The correct directive for a character is `%c`.

Comment: You have a big chance of invoking *undefined behavior* on `scanf("%s",&userChar);` by writing to out-of-range.

Comment: sizeof char is 1, you do not need to divide by `sizeof(letters[i])`; initChar is not initialized if it is not found in letters, undefined behaviour. You're ignoring the return values of scanf -> undefined behaviour.

Comment: isdigit() and isalpha() return true/false  (where false is 0) so your question indicates the parameter is not a digit and not a...z,A...Z

Comment: regarding this kind of line: `while(isdigit(userNum) == 0){`  in C, comparing a returned bool value with 0 is unnecessary and just clutters the code.  suggest using: `while( !isdigit(userNum) ) {`  similar considerations exist for the call to `isalpha()`.

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: the code block, beginning with `while(isalpha(userChar) == 0){` even after correcting the format specifier to '%c' will input invalid values, like '\n'  It would be worthwhile to consume the newline, and similar undesirable characters by inserting inside the loop: `while( getchar() != '\n' );`

Comment: if i change it to the code below, the char validator seems to work ok, but the loop keeps going even when a number is entered.                                                do{
  printf("Enter a number(3-10) : \n");
  scanf("%i",&userNum);
 }
 while(!isdigit(userNum));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have *undefined behavior* in your code. You tell `scanf` to read a string, but provide a pointer to only a single character. A non-empty string is at least two characters: The actual character in the string plus the string terminator.

When `scanf` writes the string terminator it will write somewhere in memory where it should not write.

To read a single character you should use the `"%c"` format. See e.g. [this `scanf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) for more information about the formats.

Comment: it doesnt have a problem reading the character, the problem occurs when it trys to read scanf("%d",&userNum);

    while(isdigit(userNum) == 0){

Comment: @Mikovsky Just because the program *seem* to work okay, doesn't mean there isn't anything wrong. You write data to memory where you should not write data, and that is undefined behavior, which means your whole program is ill-formed.

Answer (score 0):

`isdigit` checks whether your input are the `char`: `'0'`, `'1'`, ...

It does not check whether your inputs are `integers`. Note that `char '0'` is different from `int 0`.

Also, you should use `scanf("%c",&userChar);` instead of  `scanf("%s",&userChar);` since `userChar` is a character and not  a string.

Comment: If you really want to read a character at a time, `scanf("%c",...)` is silly; simply use `getc`.